# Error while trying to download the nvm using homebrew

Tags: homebrew

I'm trying to brew install the nvm into my machine, but when I'm doing so, it returns back the following curl error. Has anyone been through this?

Updating Homebrew...
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/nvm/manifests/0.39.0
#=#=#
curl: (92) HTTP/2 stream 0 was closed cleanly, but before getting  all response header fields, treated as error
Error: nvm: Failed to download resource "nvm_bottle_manifest"
Download failed: https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/nvm/manifests/0.39.0